# Using a querystring value in a PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, query-string

How do I write an IF condition in PHP that checks to see if the URL contained a query string  item called 'first' and its value is set to 'true'?

Comment: This is very basic stuff. You should be able to solve this yourself with an introductory PHP tutorial. Show us some code. What have you tried? How does the actual behaviour differ from the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not understand the question, but did you mean this?

```
if($_GET['first'] == 'true') {
  echo 'foo';
}
```

Comment: This was what I wanted, thanks! I'll accept this as the answer in 10mins when stackoverflow let's me.

Comment: np, ur welcome. But for the future google more :))